# Is there Stack Exchange site for questions about where to buy programming related products?

Tags: discussion

Is there a Stack Exchange site where these two questions about where to buy programming related products would be on topic?

[What are the best webshops to buy programming books?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8682954/what-are-the-best-webshops-to-buy-programming-books)
[Buying the book Code in the Philippines](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133077/buying-the-book-code-in-the-philippines)

Comment: For books I thought about http://literature.stackexchange.com/ but it seems to focus on fiction.

Comment: @N.N.: the questions listed are for book stores, not books.

Comment: @Mat Indeed, but since it was hard to find a fitting site I thought of the possibility.

Comment: You could try to create one on [Area51](https://area51.stackexchange.com/). Also I would ask such rather open questions probably rather on Reddit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I really don't think any site on the Stack Exchange network would welcome such questions.

The first one is, in my opinion, clear-cut: "best" is subjective, and the answers would be likely to degenerate into a list of vaguely spammy links to everyone's favorite online store.

The second has the merit of being a bit more specific (looking for something in a specific area), but it's still fundamentally a meta-shopping question (selecting/finding a shop rather than a product), and I don't see how that could fit. (See: [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) for the shopping part.)
You'd be better of asking your nearest/favorite bookstore to see if they can import it for you, or know someone who would.